# C# Replace with regex multiple pairs (for CLR SQL Server)

Tags: c#, clr

I just implemented that simple CLR function with C# for my SQL Server, but found that I have like other 20  more pairs to replace, and some replace done at the End of the line, so I assume it need to be Regex (?).
What would be nice way to organize this code , piece below deals with just single pair. I'm new to C#, think about put those pairs into array and loop maybe, but probably there is better solution which I can do without loop, like in Ruby.
At the same time I'm OK to repeat this block 20 times too if this will be faster.)

Tx  I see some method with aka Dictionary, but got some errors. How to tell C# that  could be  only part of the string, not the whole string ?

```
select top 1 CLR_AddressM('alpha lane') from sys.objects
```

System.Collection.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given Key was not present..

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace CLR_Functions
{
    public partial class CLRFunctions
    {    [SqlFunction( DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None, FillRowMethodName = "MyFillRowMethod"   , IsDeterministic = true)        ]

          public static string AddressM(string AddressIn)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AddressIn)) return AddressIn;

              var xmlEntityReplacements = new Dictionary<string, string> {
 { "Lane$", "Ln" }, { "Avenue", "Ave" }, { "Boulevard", "Blvd" },{ "Street", "St;" }, { ".", "" }                                                                                            };

    // Create an array and populate from the dictionary keys, then convert the array 
    // to a pipe-delimited string to serve as the regex search values and replace
    return Regex.Replace(AddressIn, string.Join("|", xmlEntityReplacements.Keys.Select(k => k.ToString()).ToArray()), m => xmlEntityReplacements[m.Value]);
}    }     }
```

Comment: xmlEntityReplacements[m.Value] - The exception is happening because m.Value isn't the dictionary key, the Regex string is

Comment: sorry don't get your comment, how to fix this. I thought that k and m go in order for this array . K is first, M is  the second Tx

Comment: Well in the case of "Lane$", the m.Value would not be the same, It would just be "Lane" so that would not be found in the dictionary. Also, the "." regex will mach any input, I thnk you want to delimit that to match a full stop, like "\."

Answer (score 1):

The "KeyNotFound" exception means you're trying to get something from the Dictionary that isn't there.

Where you're calling xmlEntityReplacements[m.Value], m.Value is not in the dictionary - in the case of the "Lane$" regex, m.Value would just be "Lane" so that could be why.

The simplest answer would just be to go through the regexes in a loop, then you still have the orginal key as a local variable that you can easily access.

```
    public static string AddressM(string addressIn)
    {
        var xmlEntityReplacements = new Dictionary<string, string> {
         { "Lane$", "Ln" }, { "Avenue", "Ave" }, { "Boulevard", "Blvd" },{ "Street", "St;" }
            //. would match all chars ...
            , { "\\.", "" }  
        };

        foreach(var kv in xmlEntityReplacements){       
            addressIn = Regex.Replace(addressIn, kv.Key, m => xmlEntityReplacements[kv.Key],
// You might also want RegexOptions.IgnoreCase here
 RegexOptions.Compiled);

        }

        return addressIn;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Sam and all, I did it the loop, thought do something more cool ). And thanks for your note re period. I fixed this with { @{ "\.", "" }